Problema modificacion contenido vector cuando se pasa por parametro a una funcion (C++ y Pybind11)
Tengo un problema al usar pybind11 para llamar a una funcion de una libreria de C++ donde se devuelve el contenido por parametro.
Estoy haciendo un ejemplo mas sencillo y no consigo que la funcion modificarPersonas me devuelva la lista de personas modificada.
Fichero personas.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace py = pybind11;

// Definición de la estructura Persona
struct Persona {
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;

    // Constructor que inicializa los valores de la estructura
    Persona(const std::string& nombre = "", int edad = 0)
        : nombre(nombre), edad(edad) {}
};

// Función que modifica el vector de estructuras Persona
void modificarPersonas(std::vector<Persona>& personas) {
    for (auto& persona : personas) {
        persona.nombre = "Modificado";  // Cambiar el nombre de cada persona
        persona.edad += 10;  // Incrementar la edad en 10 años
    }

    // Agregar una nueva persona al vector
    personas.push_back(Persona{"Nueva Persona", 25});
}

// Binding para pybind11
PYBIND11_MODULE(personas_mod, m) {
    py::class_<Persona>(m, "Persona")
        .def(py::init<const std::string&, int>())  // Constructor que acepta nombre y edad
        .def_readwrite("nombre", &Persona::nombre)
        .def_readwrite("edad", &Persona::edad);

    m.def("modificarPersonas", &modificarPersonas, py::return_value_policy::automatic, "Modifica un vector de personas");
}

Fichero main.py
import personas_mod

# Crear una lista de objetos Persona
personas = [
    personas_mod.Persona("Juan", 30),
    personas_mod.Persona("Ana", 25)
]

# Mostrar las personas antes de modificar
print("Antes de modificar:")
for persona in personas:
    print(f"Nombre: {persona.nombre}, Edad: {persona.edad}")

# Llamar a la función modificarPersonas para modificar la lista
personas_mod.modificarPersonas(personas)

# Mostrar las personas después de modificar
print("\nDespués de modificar:")
for persona in personas:
    print(f"Nombre: {persona.nombre}, Edad: {persona.edad}")

Salida obtenida:
Antes de modificar:
Nombre: Juan, Edad: 30
Nombre: Ana, Edad: 25

Después de modificar:
Nombre: Juan, Edad: 30
Nombre: Ana, Edad: 25

Salida esperada:
Antes de modificar:
Nombre: Juan, Edad: 30
Nombre: Ana, Edad: 25

Después de modificar:
Nombre: Modificado, Edad: 40
Nombre: Modificado, Edad: 35
Nombre: Nueva Persona, Edad: 25


La librería convierte los contenedores STL en sus contrapartes en Python creando una copia. Por lo tanto, los cambios que hagas en el vector no se reflejarán en Python.
Para que las referencias funcionen correctamente hay que deshabilitar este comportamiento. Lo puedes hacer con la macro PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE.
Además debes asociar el contenedor a una clase de Python, como lo harías con cualquier otra clase. Este es el ejemplo que da la documentación para un vector<int>:
py::class_<std::vector<int>>(m, "IntVector")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("clear", &std::vector<int>::clear)
    .def("pop_back", &std::vector<int>::pop_back)
    .def("__len__", [](const std::vector<int> &v) { return v.size(); })
    .def("__iter__", [](std::vector<int> &v) {
       return py::make_iterator(v.begin(), v.end());
    }, py::keep_alive<0, 1>()) /* Keep vector alive while iterator is used */
    // ....

Para no tener que asociar el contenedor manualmente, existen funciones como bind_vector y  bind_map.
En tu código quedaría así:
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

...

// Debe ir antes del PYBIND_MODULE
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<Persona>)

PYBIND11_MODULE(personas_mod, m) {
    py::class_<Persona>(m, "Persona")
        .def(py::init<const std::string&, int>())  // Constructor que acepta nombre y edad
        .def_readwrite("nombre", &Persona::nombre)
        .def_readwrite("edad", &Persona::edad);

    py::bind_vector<std::vector<Persona>>(m, "VectorPersonas");

    m.def("modificarPersonas", &modificarPersonas, py::return_value_policy::automatic, "Modifica un vector de personas");
}


Funciona a la perfección! @Mateo no sabes cuanto te agradezco tu ayuda. Me has salvado ya en 3 ocasiones, quedo a tus pies

@crossmax no es nada. No uso pybind pero investigando un poco resulta no ser tan complicado
